# searchbox logic plugin for mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, search, full-text-search, mongoose

Are there any available plugins in mongoose for user-input searchbox which searches the database based on the input?

I came across [elmongo](https://github.com/usesold/elmongo) [mongoose-fts](https://github.com/cstigler/mongoose-fts) [mongoose-text-search](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-text-search), I am still figuring them out.
Is there any standard plugin out there for this need?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @WiredPrairie. You were mentioning about effort, this question has mentioned more plugins, than your answer to another question has. It also includes the plugin which your other answer includes. (  Inspite of that i've accepted that answer, because its a fair answer)

Comment: The other answer I gave with a plugin made sense as it will very likely become part of MongooseJs when the text search feature is available for production use. The plugin and Mongoose have been written by the same person.

Comment: The StackOverflow site and community appreciates questions that show some level of effort on the part of the person asking the question has occurred before posting. "Find a ... for me" questions are generally held/closed as not a good fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[mongoose-troop#keywords](https://github.com/tblobaum/mongoose-troop#keywords) uses the stemming to return related keywords as well.

[mongoose-fulltext](https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-fulltext) seems the most comprehensive search plugin.